# How to bind List of objects to Hub Section ListView

Tags: c#, list, xaml, listview, binding

I'm having a problem with binding simple List of objects to Hub Section ListView. Here is how my Hub Page looks like. I add some objects of Group class to the List and I'm setting DataContext to a List of Groups.
[image]

Here is my Group class:
[image]

In XAML I want to display List in ListView in HubSection "Ulubione":
[image]

And here actually I have a problem because my list looks like this...
[image]

The number of list items is correct but every item is last item from my list... I have no idea what can be wrong here.

I will be really grateful for any help!

Regards!

Comment: Can you paste the XAML for your StandardDoubleLineItemTemplate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm ashamed to admit but I know where is the problem... I made my string field in Group class static and for every object the string was the same... Just deleted static identifier and everything is working fine:)